# Is there a classification for adjectives that are hard to be used negatively?

Tags: adjectives

I came across this interesting excerpt from the autobiography of the author of the Dynamic Programming method:

> “[the word dynamic] has a very interesting property as an adjective, and that is it's impossible to use the word dynamic in a pejorative sense. [...] Thus, I thought dynamic programming was a good name. It was something not even a Congressman could object to.” - Richard Bellman

And I wondered if there is a linguistic way to formalize such concept and if I could find a small list of such adjectives.

I don't believe it's really impossible to use it in a pejorative sense: "the legislation on this topic is too dynamic". But it's a scenario that I had to search a subject that is specifically meant to not be dynamic, so the "pejorativeness" comes from the antithesis. Adjectives like "fast" and "strong" can still be used pejoratively on objects that are meant to be somewhat fast or strong, like a car going too fast or a pepper that is too strong.

> *EDIT:* I guess something that is normally dynamic can be too dynamic too. "The variables in this chaotic system are too dynamic" or something like it. So maybe only affordance adjectives are really in this category?

I believe "agile" is another of such adjectives, and to use it negatively hard because it's about the *ability* to be quick. I wonder if such affordance adjectives are consistently positive adjectives.

Does this make sense as a definition?

Comment: If I'm disarming a bomb, the *last* thing I want is for my hand to be ***dynamic***.

Comment: In your examples, aren't you achieving pejorativeness by adding an adverb, e.g., *too*? Could you make *dynamic* and the other words you mention pejorative without adding an adverb?

Comment: @JasonBassford yes, but you'd probably say you wanted your hand to not be unsteady.

Comment: Vulcanologists study eruption dynamics. They probably use the adjective too.

Answer (score 2):

First, "negative" and "pejorative" are not the same. Not even close. If it were impossible to use the word *dynamic* pejoratively (which I doubt), that would say nothing about negation. Pejoration is a matter of intent on the part of the speaker, not meaning.

Second, there **is** a term for words (or phrases - "lexical items") that can't be used in negative contexts, but that has nothing to do with being pejorative. A word like *ever* or a phrase like *in weeks* is what is called a ["negative polarity item" (NPI)](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), because it's ungrammatical outside a negative environment.

- *She hasn't ever visited Turkey* but not **She has ever visited Turkey*
- *She hasn't been to the club in weeks* but not **She has been to the club in weeks*

There are [a lot of NPIs in English](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/NPIs.pdf). But there are also some PPIs, as well. These [Positive Polarity Items](http://home.uchicago.edu/%7Egiannaki/pubs/HSK.chapter64.pdf) are words or phrases that **can't** be used in a negative environment, like *would rather* and *already*

- *He would rather be home* ~ **He wouldn't rather be home*
- *He's already here* ~ **He isn't already here*

But, once again, this has nothing to do with using a word pejoratively, or with a better slogan for a programming system.

Answer (score 0):

They have a positive [connotation](https://literarydevices.net/connotation/).

> Connotation refers to a meaning that is implied by a word apart from the thing which it describes explicitly.

and

> Words may have positive or negative connotations that depend upon the social, cultural, and personal experiences of individuals. For example, the words childish, childlike and youthful have the same denotative, but different connotative, meanings. Childish and childlike have a negative connotation, as they refer to immature behavior of a person. Whereas, youthful implies that a person is lively and energetic.

Comment: Not sure I agree that your words have the same *denotative* meaning. For example, does *childlike* have the same denotation as *childish* and *youthful*? How would you support this assertion re denotation?

Comment: 'Words may have positive or negative connotations that depend upon the social, cultural, and personal experiences of individuals' implies that connotations are at least to some degree specific to the individual (this is the definition I use). However, as OP says, 'dynamic' almost always has a positive (in the upbeat, go-ahead, laudatory sense) connotation, no matter who is considering the word. //// As Richard says, 'childish' and 'childlike' have different **denotations** (dictionary definitions).